# Transforming a string to a tuple

Tags: python

Given a string  "key: content" I want to return a tuple (key, content)
I have found some cryptic ways to do it. Is there an easy way to do this in python

Comment: `tuple(mystring.split(': '))`? Unless you need to convert the elements to variables of those names?

Answer (score 2):

As @ShadowRanger suggested, using the `tuple()` function is one of the easiest ways to convert into a tulpe. We separate the string into two parts by using `string.split()` function.
So, we implement it this way:

```
string = "key: content"               # given string
mytuple = tuple(string.split(": "))   # split the string from ": " and convert it into a tuple
print(mytuple)

>>> ("key", "content")
```

**Note:** This can also be achieved by using `for` loop, but it is tedious and more time-consuming.